# Stripe product description in two languages

Tags: stripe-payments

I have created products in stripe. The description of those products is in english. I cannot figure out how to enter a second description in a another language.

When I create a checkout session in french, I would like to the product descriptions to show up in french in the shopping cart. Right now, the checkout session is in french except for the product names and descriptions which are in english.

Comment: Personally, I'm leaning towards having localisation keys as placeholders in product descriptions and at the time of reading the products on the frontend I retrieve my localised strings from the localisation tool, be it a static JSON or an API.

Comment: Why isn't anyone talking about that? You have a multi-billion dollars company such as Stripe that make a whole Checkout system with i18n customization and they ... Didn't think of having product descriptions translated? I'm kind of shocked and trying to find a solution right now, but I find it ridiculous for a company like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Product can only have 1 description unfortunately, and you are correct that description will show in Checkout Session.

If you know your audience language beforehand, probably you could create separated Products with respective languages and show them accordingly.

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea to have two products for the same product.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution proposed by [sweethuman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5644574/sweethuman) (using description/title as translation keys) is good if people managing your stripe products also have access to your translations.

I feel like its better to have everything available in stripe directly, so, even if its far from being a good solution, I did the following:

Set product metadata to `en_<fieldName>` and `fr_<fieldName>` then, in your code you can retrieve the correct product field using the locale.

For example, using [Nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) (with [next-international](https://github.com/QuiiBz/next-international)):

```js
import { stripe } from "@/lib/stripe";
import { getCurrentLocale } from "locales/server";
import { cache } from "react";

export default async function Product(props: { productId: string }) {
    const locale = getCurrentLocale();
    const product = await getProduct(props.productId);
    return (
        <>
            <h3>{product.metadata[`${locale}_title`]}</h3>
            <p>{product.metadata[`${locale}_description`]}</p>
        </>
    );
}

export const getProduct = cache(async (id: string) => {
    return await stripe.products.retrieve(id);
});
```

We can even improve a little bit the code by instead removing the current locale from localized metadata keys and replace them in the original product data, the idea is to transform:

```json
{
    name: "Product",
    description: "Product description",
    metadata: {
        "es_name": "Producto",
        "es_description": "Descripción de producto",
        "fr_name": "Produit",
        "fr_description": "Description du produit"
    },
}
```

to the following if the current locale is `fr`:

```json
{
    name: "Produit",
    description: "Description du produit",
    metadata: {
        "es_name": "Producto",
        "es_description": "Descripción de producto",
        "fr_name": "Produit",
        "fr_description": "Description du produit"
    },
}
```

Which would allow the developer to ignore all that non-sense of composing metadata fields name based on the locale, and he could access the `product.title` directly:

```js
import { stripe } from "@/lib/stripe";
import { getCurrentLocale } from "locales/server";
import { cache } from "react";
import Stripe from "stripe";

type Product = Stripe.Response<Stripe.Product>;

export default async function Product(props: { productId: string }) {
    const locale = getCurrentLocale();
    const product = await getProduct(props.productId, locale);

    return (
        <>
            <h3>{product.name}</h3>
            <p>{product.description}</p>
        </>
    );
}

export const getProduct = cache(async (id: string, locale?: string) => {
    let product = await stripe.products.retrieve(id);
    if (locale) {
        product = localizedProduct(product, locale);
    }
    return product;
});

const LOCALIZED_FIELDS = ["name", "description", "statement_descriptor", "unit_label"];

function localizedProduct(product: Product, locale: string): Product {
    const localizedMetadata = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(product.metadata)
            .filter(([localizedK, _]) => localizedK.startsWith(`${locale}_`))
            .map(([localizedK, v]) => [localizedK.slice(locale.length + 1), v])
            .filter(([k, _]) => LOCALIZED_FIELDS.includes(k)),
    );
    return {
        ...product,
        ...localizedMetadata,
        metadata: product.metadata,
    };
}
```

The last part of the return `metadata: product.metadata` is only there to avoid replacing the actual metadata if a metadata field is itself named `<locale>_metadata` but also to keep all non localized metadata fields.

Comment: Nice solution, thank you! Are you also able to localize the product title in Stripe Checkout?